# circularly linked static libraries (linux )undefined libraries

Tags: static-libraries

I did a build for static libraries and put then at a location. Now when i build my source i get `UNDEFINED REFERENCES` for inter library calls. For example:

> `/home/xyz/lib/libA.a(ClassA.a)`:undefined reference to `classB::funB()`

here `classB.a` is also a static library .

In my source's project file the static linking order is :

```
LIBS+=   -lclassB -lclassA
```

Now when i reverse the libraries order i start getting error in classes of library B for function calls inside library A.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of situation you generally need e.g.

```
LIBS += -lclassA -lclassB -lclassA
```

Linking the classA library twice helps to resolve the circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok friends I have found the solution .

I was using qmake build tool on gcc , i just needeed to tell qmake that some of my static libraries are circularly dependent .

So i modified my .pro file with a qmake linker flag

```
   QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl , --start-group --end-group
```

gcc's documentation says that you need to put your archive names between --start-group --end-group  , but qmake is smart enough to find out the dependent libs , and will do that automatically .

Have Fun .